# MVC session expires - continue where left

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

We have an internal ASP.NET MVC application that requires a logon. Log on works great and does what's expected. We have a session expiration of 5 minutes. After sitting on a single page for that period of time, the user has lost the session. If they attempt to refresh the current page or browse to another, they will get a log on page.

**My question** is (after reloggin in) where to tell MVCto redirect to their (refresh/browse) attempt instead of getting HOME controller page always ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally this should happen automatically. When an anonymous user hits a protected resource (he is anonymous because his session expired), the FormsAuthentication module intercepts this requests and redirects to the `loginUrl` you registered in your web.config by appending a `ReturnUrl` query string parameter pointing to the protected resource.

So if for example you configured `~/Account/LogOn` to be your logon url, and the anonymous user attempts to hit the `~/Foo/Bar` protected resource he will be redirected to `~/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2FFoo%2FBar`.

Then he will be presented with a login page where he will input his credentials and submit the form to the `[HttpPost]` `LogOn` action on the `Account` controller. The credentials will be validated and if valid, a new forms authentication cookie will be generated and the user redirected to the initially requested protected resource.

Here's the respective code from the LogOn action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Notice how the user is redirected either to the default `Home/Index` or to the `returnUrl` parameter upon successful authentication.

Now of course all this story that I told here is true for the default ASP.NET MVC template created by Visual Studio. If for some reason you have modified this template this might explain the behavior you are observing.

In any case the thing to remember from my answer is that if you are using Forms Authentication, the module will pass as `ReturnUrl` query string parameter the initially requested protected resource to the configured logon page. So it's up to you to redirect the user to this page upon successful authentication.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is integrated out of the box when you create a new ASP.Net MVC project.

In short, the requested URL is sent as a parameter to the `Index` action of the `AccountController` by the MVC framework and then becomes a parameter to the log in page URL:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
  ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

  return View();
}
```

When the user posts his credentials and the log in is successful, the `returnUrl` is used to redirect the user to the originally requested page:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
  {

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
  }

  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  ModelState.AddModelError("LogInIncorrectError", Resources.LogInIncorrectError);

  return View(model);
}

private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
  if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
  {
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I suggest you create a new project and see how it behaves...

Note that this only works for `HttpGet`, if the user was submitting a form, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Generally this happens out-of-the-box with the `AccountController` in an ASP.NET MVC application.  Take a look at the default `Login` action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}

// later...
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

When the session expires and the user is redirected to the login page, the system *should* be supplying a `returnUrl` parameter to that redirect.  If it's not in your application, what in your application is different from the default in this case?

Notice how the first `Login` action, which just renders the login page after the user is redirected to it, includes that value in the `ViewBag`.  The default view for this page adds the value to the `form` element so it will be included in the login POST request.  The second `Login` action, which receives that request, then directs the user to that supplied URL (or to a default of `/Index/Home`, as seen in the helper method).

Is your application maintaining this chain of events?  If not, where does this chain of events break?  In keeping with convention, you should be:

1. Receiving the `returnUrl` from the session expiration redirect.
2. Including the `returnUrl` in the login form.
3. Redirecting the user to the `returnUrl` after a successful login.